# SQL Server FTS is returning inaccurate results

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

We have a column in our table that is indexed for full text search. In it we store values such as

```
<zNSIC>1010</zNSIC>
```

The value within the tags could be anything so then we create a search query similar to...

```
SELECT KEY 
FROM CONTAINSTABLE(SearchTable, SearchText, '("<zNSIC>15*")')
```

and it should return any record where the `SearchText` column has the `zNSIC` tag with a value like 1500, 1501, 1502, etc. This is working however I'm also getting back a couple of records where there is no `zNSIC` tag starting with 15. The closest match I can find in the two records are

```
<zNSIC>DM15</zNSIC>
```

I can't figure out why it's considering the DM in that value as a match. Any ideas? This is SQL Server 2014.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "15" is parsed out as a separate phrase as can be seen here:

```
select keyword, special_term, display_term, source_term
    from sys.dm_fts_parser('("<zNSIC>15*")', 1033, 0, 0);

keyword                 special_term    display_term    source_term
0x007A006E007300690063  Exact Match     znsic           <zNSIC>15
0x00310035              Exact Match     15              <zNSIC>15
0x006E006E00310035      Exact Match     nn15            <zNSIC>15
```

Comment: Ok, so I'm assuming it's using the > as a wordbreaker?  Is there a way to ignore that?

Comment: @geoffswartz This may be helpful: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/configure-and-manage-word-breakers-and-stemmers-for-search